# ¿Cómo insertar datos de un select y radio usando setencias preparadas MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy insertando datos, en el uso de `input radio` recibo datos nulos, trate de agregar un `value` pero sigo insertando datos nulos.

```
<input name="indexar" type="radio" id="case1" value="indexar">Indexar <input name="noindexar" type="radio" id="case2" value="noindexar">No Indexar<br>
```

Cómo se insertar datos de `option` seleccionados desde un `select`

**form.php**

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <select name="language">
  <?php
    $datos = array("Idioma...","en","es");
    for($i=0; $i<count($datos); $i++) {
      if($datos[$i]==$seleccionado) {
        echo "<option value='".$datos[$i]."'>".$datos[$i]."</option>";
      }else {
        echo "<option value='".$datos[$i]."'>".$datos[$i]."</option>";
      }
    }
  ?>
  </select><br>
  <input name="indexar" type="radio" id="case1">Indexar <input name="noindexar" type="radio" id="case2">No Indexar<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="noindexar" value="indexar">Indexar<br>
  <label>Titulo:</label>
  <input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Titulo"/><br /><br />
  <label>Mini Titulo:</label>
  <input type="text" name="mini_title" id="mini_title" placeholder="Mini Titulo"/><br/><br />
  <label>Detalle:</label>
  <textarea name="detail">Detalle</textarea><br /><br />
  <input type="text" name="main_cover" id="main_cover" placeholder="Categoria"/>
  <input type="submit" value=" Submit " name="submit"/><br />
</form>
```

**insert.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
  $index = $_POST['indexar'];
  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $mini_title = $_POST['mini_title'];
  $detail = $_POST['detail'];
  $main_cover = $_POST['main_cover'];

  $stmt = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO products (index, title, mini_title, detail, main_cover) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
  $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $index,$title,$mini_title,$detail,$main_cover);
  if($stmt->execute()){
      echo "Datos insertados correctamente";

  } else {
      echo "Error";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: que error te genera el presente codigo ?

Comment: No veo que recibas o insertes los valores de `indexar` y `noindexar`

Comment: @alanfcm Me olvide agregarlo, ya esta, como estaba practicando me olvide agregarlos

Comment: @srJJ No me genera ningún error en el formulario `input radio` pero no inserta datos, en el `select option` no se como insertar datos seleccionados.

Comment: Para capturar tu select usa `$lenguaje = $_POST["language"];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para los elementos de tipo radio, debes tener ambas opciones con el mismo nombre *(index para el ejemplo)*  y con los `value`, desee agregar a su BD.

```
<input name="index" type="radio" id="case1" value="indexar">Indexar 
<input name="index" type="radio" id="case2"  value="no indexar">No Indexar<br>
```

Ahora el detalle que puede causar posibles errores es que está utilizando [una palabra reservada](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html) para una columna como `index`, lo cuál puede ocasionar errores de sintaxis típicos. Para esto recomendar evitar utilizar estas palabras reservadas para identificadores de tablas o columnas.

Otra opción sería, ojo que aún faltaría añadir el valor del `select` con nombre  `language` a su query.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $lenguaje = $_POST["language"];
    $index = $_POST['index'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $mini_title = $_POST['mini_title'];
    $detail = $_POST['detail'];
    $main_cover = $_POST['main_cover'];

    $stmt = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO products 
    (`language`, `index`,`title`, `mini_title`, `detail`, `main_cover`) VALUES (? , ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    if ( false===$stmt ) {
        die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($conexion->error));
    }
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $lenguaje, $index,$title,$mini_title,$detail,$main_cover);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        echo "Datos insertados correctamente";

    } else {
        echo "Error";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Interesante amigo y el valor del `lenguage` como lo insertas en la tabla/base de datos.

Comment: Igual que los demás valores, no aparece la columna de `lenguage` en su pregunta para abarcar ese detalle también. Cual es. Nombre de la columna en su bd para language

Comment: Bernardo actualice para el campo language, asumí que la columna en su base de datos se llama así.

Comment: Gracias amigo :)

Answer (score 1):

en el caso de los `Radio input` para que actuen al unizono deben compartir el mismo name, ya que si es name es diferente entonces si no esta marcado tomara valor de null, en cambio si tiene el mimo nombre siempre tendra un valor que enviar, en tu ejemplo seria asi:

```
<input name="indexar" type="radio" id="case1" value="indexar">Indexar 
<input name="indexar" type="radio" id="case2" value="noindexar">No Indexar<br>
```

y para recibir el valor es.

```
$index = $_POST['indexar'];
```

en el caso del `select` lo hacer bien, solo falta es que captures su valor en el archivo `insert.php` como si fuera un input, asi:

```
$lenguaje = $_POST["language"];
```

Te dejo el [Link Radio](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp) donde te ilustraran quizas algo mejor...

Espero te sirva, estare atento...